# How to enable Context menu in Chrome when the web application overwrite with it's own

Tags: contextmenu, google-translate

I am using a web application in French and i want to translate it to English using the Chrome Context Menu (Right Click >> Translate to English).
But when i try to right click i see the web application's own context menu instead of chrome one.
Is there a way to view the chrome context menu in this case please.

Comment: Please provide more information about the nature of the web app (ideally the name/URL).

Comment: Hi Josh, It's an enterprise web application built in Java and EXT-JS with the URL for our integration environment is http://staging.ls.dc1.fr.grp.io:19000/home.html
Please see the image here for your reference.
https://ibb.co/KbscRBq